# How to let little menu with 3 links act responsive inside header?

Tags: html, css

I made my website as responsive as possible(don't wanna know something about bootstrap). The only thing that doesn't stay in its place (which needs to stay in the middle). Here is my code:

```css
    #header {
     position:fixed;
     display:block;
     width:100%;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     padding-left:0vmax;
     padding-right:5vmax;
     z-index:99999;
     height:8vmax;
     max-height:8vmax;
      transition: .3s linear;
     box-sizing:border-box;
       background-color: rgba(243,243,243,1.00);
     
       }
    
    #menuwrapper {
     display:block;
     float:right;
     width:55vmax;
     margin-top:0.35vmax;
     margin-right:17vmax;
     height:8vmax;
     max-height:8vmax;
     overflow:hidden;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     position:relative; 
    }
    
   

     #menu {position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;display:table;padding: 2.5vmax; word-wrap:break-word;}
        #menu ul {word-spacing:2vmax;font-size:1.35vmax;padding:0;padding-bottom:0vmax;margin: 0 1vmax;}
        #menu li {display:inline-block;padding: 0vmax;}
        .rechts {display: table-cell;width: 1px;vertical-align: middle;white-space: nowrap;}
        #menu ul li a {height:8vmax;text-decoration:none;color:grey;transition: color .45s ease-in-out;margin-right:7.5vmax;}
        #menu ul li a:hover {color:#3f92c3;}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
    <div id="menuwrapper">
    
    <div id="menu">
      <ul class="pad">
        </ul>
    <ul class="rechts">
    
    <li><a class="a1" id="page1" href="javascript:;">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="a1" id="page2" href="javascript:;">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a class="a1" id="page3" href="javascript:;">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45ztnajs/1/) but i can't see that it goes to much to the left like i saw on a tablet.

It is a tablet of work and it has long height. On my website it's better noticable [My website](http://www.gester.nl) If i change the height inside the desktop version. Then you see that the menu goes left and the first menu word disappears.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @JoelBonetR do NOT add any "code moved to a snippet" nonsense to the **question body** in your future edit suggestions! That's what the comment input is there for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding default properties without reason.

I tried to clean your css code a little bit, deleting what's not necessary.
I think now works as you expect, if not, specify a little bit more and i'll edit the code to help you understand how to do what you need.

```css
#header {
     position:fixed;
     display:block;
     width:100%;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     padding-left:0vmax;
     padding-right:5vmax;
     z-index:99999;
     height:8vmax;
     max-height:8vmax;
     transition: .3s linear;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     background-color: rgba(243,243,243,1.00);
     
       }
    
    #menuwrapper {
     display:block;
     float:right;
     margin-top:0.35vmax;
     margin-right:17vmax;
     height:8vmax;
     max-height:8vmax;
     overflow:hidden;
     box-sizing:border-box;
     position:relative; 
    }
    
   

     #menu {padding: 2.5vmax; word-wrap:break-word;}
     
        #menu ul {word-spacing:2vmax;font-size:1.35vmax;padding:0;padding-bottom:0vmax;margin: 0 1vmax;}
        
        #menu li {display:inline-block;padding: 0vmax;}
        
        .rechts {vertical-align: middle; white-space: nowrap;}
        
        #menu ul li a {height:8vmax;text-decoration:none;color:grey;transition: color .45s ease-in-out;margin-right:7.5vmax;}
        #menu ul li a:hover {color:#3f92c3;}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="menuwrapper">
    
    <div id="menu">
      <ul class="pad">
        </ul>
    <ul class="rechts">
    
    <li><a class="a1" id="page1" href="javascript:;">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="a1" id="page2" href="javascript:;">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a class="a1" id="page3" href="javascript:;">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You totally fixed it for me, thanks for your time and effort!